# Get the contents of the entire page that requires scrolling python

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I want to get the content of this page:
[Page](https://bama.ir/car/samand-lx)

and find the `a` tags that contain the link to be transferred to the information page of each ***car*** and put them in a `list` so that I can open them one by one later.
so I have this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar


baseUrl = 'https://bama.ir/car/'
brand = 'samand-lx'
url = f'{baseUrl}{brand}'

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
response = opener.open(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all('a', class_='bama-ad')
links = list(map(lambda x: 'https://bama.ir'+x['href'], links))
print(links)
```

and return this output:

```
['https://bama.ir/car/detail-hbr06v3g-samand-lx-basic-1392', 'https://bama.ir/car/detail-pa4bsrlr-samand-lx-basic-1398', 'https://bama.ir/car/detail-dcuahpx9-samand-lx-ef7-1398']
```

is almost correct but I need At least 50 of them not only 3!

This site does not use pages 1, 2, and 3... to view the rest of the content and need scrolling to see new ***Cars***.
My question is how to adjust the length of the page so that at least 50 cars appear for me.

Comment: If you look closely at the network tab, you will see an API with the ability to navigate through pages and get all the useful information. [API](https://bama.ir/cad/api/search?vehicle=samand%2Clx&pageIndex=1)

Comment: Yes, I was looking for information but I did not find a document about the API. Thank you for showing it to me, and how did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to extract information from the desired page using requests and BeautifulSoup alone because the page loads additional entries through JavaScript as the user scrolls down. Instead, you can use selenium to simulate the actions of a real user by programmatically sending page down key press events, which will allow you to extract the desired information.